# GenericDAO and ClassCast

Tags: java, generics, dao

I've wrote the following GenericDAO as in the code below

```
abstract public class DAO <T extends AbstractBusinessObject> {

// CRUD: create, read, update, delete 

public abstract T create(Class<T> abObj);

public abstract T read();

public abstract void update(T abObj);

public abstract void delete(T abObj);
}
```

Also I have implemented some commands via Command Pattern which interact with DAOInMemory extending GenericDAO in order to perform tasks like "register user name password".

```
public class RegisterUserCommand extends AbstractCommand {

public RegisterUserCommand() {
    ...
}

...
@Override
public void execute(String[] cmdArgs) {

        // class cast here
        User userObject = (User) daoInstance.create(User.class);

        //why doesn't this work?
        //User userObject = daoInstance.create(User.class); 

    }
}}
```

I don't understand why I have to cast result of the `daoInstance.create(User.class)` when DAOInMemory has already cast operation in `create`-method?

```
public class DAOInMemory<T extends AbstractBusinessObject> extends DAO<T> {
    ...

public DAOInMemory() {
    ...


public T create(Class<T> abstractObjectType) {

    IDGenerator IDGenerator = IDGenerator.getInstance();

    if (User.class.isAssignableFrom(abstractObjectType)) {
        BigInteger id = IDGenerator.getID();
        User user = new User(id);
        return (T) user;
    }
```

Could you explain this behaviour of Java?

**EDIT:** I forgot to add that `public class User extends AbstractBusinessObject`

Comment: I guess you're coming from `.NET` - but in `java` coding conventions variable names start with a lower letter ( unless it's a constant - then all capitals should be used )

Comment: how are you defining daoInstance?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do...you're using too much of generics :) Why would you use a generic class `DAOInMemory` and then return a specific type? I would suggest you create a `UserDAO` class instead which would implement `DAO<User>` or extend `DAOInMemory<User>` class for the actual implementation.

Comment: @IanMc Well, instantiation is just `DAO daoInstance = new DAOInMemory()`at the top of the class which registers all commands like `RegisterUserCommand`;
And constructor of `RegisterUserCommand` is 
`public RegisterUserCommand(DAO daoInstance) {
        super(daoInstance);
    }`

Comment: Thank you.  This explains the cast requirement (see my answer).  Please be encouraged to use Generics throughout your code, including the DAO instantiation (see explanation in answer).  Regards.

Comment: Interestingly (showing the power of Generics), you did not need to tell us that User extends AbstractBusinessObject.  The use of:  abstract public class DAO <T extends AbstractBusinessObject> forces it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be avoiding the use of Generics when you instantiate your DAO class.

Example 1: (Requires a cast):

```
DAO dao = new DAOInMemory();
User user = (User) dao.create(User.class);
```

Example 2:  (Does not require a cast):

```
DAO<User> dao = new DAOInMemory<User>();
User user = dao.create(User.class);
```

Comment: So, is the first variant more preferrable?

Comment: No, you should be encouraged to use variant #2.  Example one is a raw type, which loses the value of Generics (thus the need to cast) and is subject to runtime errors.  The benefit of Generics is that class mismatch errors are caught at compile time, which is superior to runtime exceptions.

Comment: Much obliged for your explanations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Cast because `T` is not necessarily `User`.

In fact, this code might cause class cast exception, since your generic definitions is `T extends AbstractBusinessObject` which does not imply `User`

Comment: Actually, `User extends AbstractBusinessObject` in my code

Comment: Still - think of a scanario where T is some other subclass of `AbstractBusinessObject`, not User. Casting user to it  in your create method will cause class cast exception